# Prove that, in a $C^*$-algebra, if a self-adjoint $a$ has infinite spectrum, then the algebra is infinite-dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Question:Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, $a \in A$ self adjoint. Suppose that the spectrum $\sigma(a)$ is an infinite set. Show that $A$ is infinite-dimensional.

**How can i prove it?**

I guess: Let $A$ be finite dimensional. Thus it is isomorphic with direct sum of matrixes $(n_i)$.$\sigma(a)$ is eigenvalue of this direct sum. Can  I say then that $\sigma(a)$ is finite?
Is it true?

Comment: How many eigenvalues can a finite matrix have?

Comment: Is eigenvalue of M_n(A) finite?

Comment: Do you mean $M_n(\mathbb C)$? If $A$ is finite dimensional then $M_n(A)\cong M_n(\mathbb C)\otimes A$ is still finite dimensional, i.e. a direct sum of *finitely many* full matrix algebras. Hence it is enough to consider just one of them and a self-adjoint element. If you diagonalise it, how many eigenvalues would you find?

Comment: Yes.You are right.

Comment: we can say that If A has finite-dimensional then M_n(A) has finite eigenvalue

Answer (score 3):

Consider abelian C*-algebra $C^*(a)$ which is infinite dimensional ( because $\sigma(a)$ is infinite). Also $C^*(a) \subset A$ which implies that $A$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Hi Niki.why is C^*(a) infinite dimensional?σ(a) is infinite set

Comment: I think you use functional calculus.C(σ(a)) has infinite dimensional and isomorphic with C^*(a)

Comment: @alex: yes, you are right. $C(\sigma(a))$ is finite dimensional and isomorphic to $C^*(a)$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $k$ field and $A$ a finite dimensional $k$ algebra. Then the spectrum of any element is finite.

Step 1. Every element $a$ of $A$ satisfies a polynomial equation of degree at most $n= \dim_{k} A$. Indeed, the elements $1$, $a$, $\ldots$, $a^n$ are linearly dependent.

Step 2. Let $a$ satisfying a polynomial equation $P(a) = 0$, where $P \in k[X]$ , $P\ne 0$.  Then the spectrum of $a$ is included in the zero set of $P$, so has cardinality at most $\deg P$, hence finite.

Indeed, let $\sigma \in k$ so that $P(\sigma) \ne 0$. We have the division with remainder
$$P(X) = (X-\sigma) \cdot Q(X) + P(\sigma)$$

Plug $a$ instead of $X$ above and get 
$$0 = P(a) = (a - \sigma ) \cdot Q(a) + P(\sigma)$$
so $(a-\sigma)^{-1}$ is invertible with inverse $- P(\sigma)^{-1} \cdot Q(a)$

From the above we see that the spectrum of any element has cardinality $\le \dim_k(A)$.

Comment: Dear Oranges kid.I try to get your answer.But I can solve it with functional calculus.